# How to detect color from sphere and block?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I need that when my green sphere collision with my green block, the games continues and when my red sphere collision with my green block, the games end. how??

collision script:

`public class Colision : MonoBehaviour {`

```
public Text points;
int contador=0;

void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col){
    if ( col.gameObject.name == "Cube") {

        col.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        contador = contador + 1;
        points.text = "" + contador;

    }


    if ( col.gameObject.name == "Cube(Clone)") {
        col.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        contador = contador + 1;
        points.text = "" + contador;


    }
```

`}`

Answer (score 0):

From your text I understand that when assuming player hit green box then nothing happen. But when he hits red box then game ends. You didnt define what "end" means in your case but I guess that loading new scene with something like "game over" text is what you mean by that. So I did that in my answer.

1.Put this script on player (or object what will collide with red box) and give it some collider.

2.Create new tag in unity and name it "Red".

3.Assign this tag to objects which will end game.

4.Set red objects colliders "Is trigger" on TRUE and their tag on Red.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class collisionTest : MonoBehaviour {

  void OnTriggerEnter(Collider trigg)
  {
    if (trigg.gameObject.tag == "Red")
    {
        Debug.Log("I have collided with trigger" + trigg.gameObject.name);
        //do your ending stuff
        SceneManager.LoadScene("exit",LoadSceneMode.Single);
    }
  }
}
```